# error MSB1001: Unknown switch - Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When compiling my solution in Visual Studio 2017 RC I get

```
C:\Code\src\MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
  Switch: -

  For switch syntax, type "MSBuild /help"
```

On every project.

I can compile the solution using Visual Studio 2015. I have changed the build output to 'Diagnostic' and this is still all that I see.

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Comment: I can't easily share the solution as it has 28 projects that I can't easily sanitise... if you really want I can remove them one by one and maybe add a new blank one for sharing.

Comment: It sounds like your projects have some modifications that are causing this. It'll be hard to diagnose the issue without seeing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was lightweight solution load. I hit F4 on the solution and disabled lightweight load, closed VS and re opened the solution, and it works fine now.

I've just re-enabled lightweight load, and sure enough I get the same error - definitely lightweight load.

Comment: I had the same problem. Disabling lightweight load restored the build functionality.

Comment: Can confirm. 80 projects+ solution, same thing

Comment: It's probably worth noting that in vs2017.. "Thank you for your feedback! We have fixed this issue and it's available in in 15.5. Lightweight solution mode was deprecated. Thank you for helping us build a better Visual Studio!" Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/lightweight-solution-tip-to-enable-try-it/26316